# How do I view a certain section of my dataset of people (for example, only females)?

Tags: r

I have a dataset called "data" and I have a column in it called "gender." I want to look at all the data where "gender" = F only. How would I go about doing this in R?

Comment: The language you are working with is just "R".  I don't want to sound rude but it does seem like you should be spending some time in some introductory materials.  Read the [r] tag wiki for some resources to peruse http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the data set on the gender variable such that it equals `"F"`.

`data[data$gender == "F", ]`

Answer (score 3):

In the new version of R studio when you click on the data frame name or use the View() command there is a filter option for each variable similar to excel

The other option is to run:

```
data[data$gender == "F",]
```

Comment: Hmmm this brought back 0 observations.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't use the exact names of your specific dataset. I've just changed f to F and df to data and it should now work fine